# How to create basic Node.js project with materialwebcomponents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, polymer

I am relatively new to Node.js.  This is a very simple program so far, meant to just test the incorporation of [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/blob/master/README.md).  I followed the instructions step-by-step in the readme, and this is what I have so far:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-polymer", "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Intro to Polymer", "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": { "start": "node index.js" },
  "author": "vcapra1", "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": { "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.0.2" }
}
```

index.js

```
http = require('http')
fs = require('fs')

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.statusCode = 200
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  let filename = "./" + request.url
  if (request.url.startsWith("/@")) {
    filename = "./node_modules/" + request.url
  } else if (request.url == "/") {
    filename = "./index.html"
  } else {
    response.statusCode = 404;
    response.end("404 Not Found");
  }
  fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
    console.log("Request: ", request.url);
    response.end(data)
  })
}).listen(3000)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MWC Test</title>
    <script src="@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="@material/mwc-icon/mwc-icon.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World
    <mwc-icon>sentiment_very_satisfied</mwc-icon>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I run the following command in the project folder:

```
polymer serve
```

I've also tried starting it with npm using:

```
npm start
```

Both commands allow me to go to the webpage at http://localhost:XXXX, but each time all I get is the text "Hello, World sentiment_very_satisfied", and the plain text stays there with no icon.

I'm not really sure what I'm missing.  I find it strange that the script src attributes reference @webcomponents as a sibling folder while said folder is actually in the node_modules directory, so I tried changing that, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by running with

`polymer serve --module-resolution=node --npm`.

This tells polymer-cli to transform npm style references to relative references when serving files. Although it doesn't work for index.html for some reason, so relative paths are required there:

```
<script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="node_modules/@material/mwc-icon/mwc-icon.js"></script>
```

You can read more here https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-03-23-polymer-3-latest-preview#packagenames

Comment: This works, but there are some issues.  First, the icon doesn't appear immediately.  I'm sure there's an easy way to make it hidden until it loads though, so I'm not to worried about that.  However, sometimes the image doesn't load at all.  It seems completely random, but if I refresh the page over and over, it only shows the icon about half the time.  The other half of the time it just makes the name of the icon show in a larger font.  Have you had this issue?

Comment: It won't show until the font is loaded containing the icon. Though I've never had it not load at all. Are there any errors in you console or network tab?